# Access ODBC: Wrong value returned for numeric (integer) fields

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc, unixodbc

I'm building an application that needs to import Microsoft Access files. The application is written in php, and follow the following tutorial to set up the environment. (https://gist.github.com/amirkdv/9672857)

Downloaded the ODBC driver libmdbodbc1 and had problem getting numerical values ​​. Thinking that the problem may be the driver, then downloaded the trial driver provided by Easysoft , and to my surprise I had the same problem. (http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html#section=tab-1)

In the file I'm using I have the following structure:

[image]

When I run the query in the database it returns me the following result:

[image]

I am running the query directly from the command line through the mb -tools , because at first I thought it might be a problem with PHP

I've tried everything imaginable , since retraced every step , and both the command line , as by PHP get the same result. Already tested on another machine as well.

Note: I've tried querying with other files and got the same error , then I believe the problem is not the file .

Note2: I solved the problem. The return value is the value in double format . Probably the driver was written in C that is double this way. By using the EasySoft driver with PHP I got the correct representation . Soon the problem was with the `libmdbodbc1` driver.I will look for an alternative to the EasySoft driver since it is very expensive.

Comment: Clearly, the values are divided by 100. So don't have some percent formatting/handling hidden somewhere causing your values to be regarded as percent values, returning the decimal equivalent of these?

Answer (score 2):

The area code number is being retrieved as a floating point value<sup>*</sup>, and the default format for floating point numbers is (apparently) scientific notation, i.e.

```
201 = 2.01 times 10 to the power of 2 --> 2.01000e+02
```

If your ODBC driver (MDB Tools?) supports the `CInt()` function to convert the value to an integer then you could use

```sql
SELECT CInt(area_code) AS areacode ...
```

Or, if that doesn't work you could try using the `CONVERT()` ODBC function

```sql
SELECT { fn CONVERT(area_code, SQL_INTEGER) } AS areacode ...
```

Otherwise, you can just convert the value to integer after you retrieve it using a PHP function like [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

<sup>*</sup> One common way for this to happen is when numeric values are imported from Excel into Access. By default, numeric values are imported into Access as `Double`, even if they are actually just integers in the Excel document.